# Multiple Flavors and Modules

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I have a multiple module app with multiple favors.

1. Is there a way to only change the top 'app' Build Variant and make the sub-modules build the same way? Or do I need to change each module?
2. Is there a way to configure build types-flavor dependency in less code? This is 'stupid' config

   //Module 1 dependency configuration
   flavor1DebugCompile project(path: ':module1', configuration: 'flavor1DebugCompile')
   flavor2DebugCompile project(path: ':module1', configuration: 'flavor2DebugCompile')
   flavor1ReleaseCompile project(path: ':module1', configuration: 'flavor1ReleaseCompile')
   flavor2ReleaseCompile project(path: ':module1', configuration: 'flavor2ReleaseCompile')

   //Module 2 dependency configuration
   flavor1DebugCompile project(path: ':module2', configuration: 'flavor1DebugCompile')
   flavor2DebugCompile project(path: ':module2', configuration: 'flavor2DebugCompile')
   flavor1ReleaseCompile project(path: ':module2', configuration: 'flavor1ReleaseCompile')
   flavor2ReleaseCompile project(path: ':module2', configuration: 'flavor2ReleaseCompile')

   //Module 3 dependency configuration
      ...
   //Module 4 dependency configuration
      ...